# Apple Push Notification works with Development certificate on Production service URL

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Currently application does not have production certificates. I tried to send push notification to application with development certificate to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com and result was error: Invalid token. Then I changed service URL to gateway.push.apple.com and it managed to send.

How can this even be possible?

Comment: You must be using wrong certificate. It's hard to find error, but I suggest you follow http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: @Yanchi Can this be tru if http://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/create_development_certificate-480x276.png shows only development certificates. As i mentioned, there are no production certs.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem likely that you managed to send a push notification to the production env using a development certificate.

The fact that, initially, when you sent the push to `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` and got "invalid token", means that your the app on your device was signed with a production provisioning profile, which means you must have a production push certificate. That's the reason you got a production device token, which is invalid in the development push env.

The fact that later you succeeded to send a notification (and I'm assuming that by `managed to send` you mean that the notification reached your device) with that production device token to the production push env means that you were most likely using a production push certificate.

Comment: Just managed to send. Some while has passed and notification is not on device yet.

Comment: @chba in that case, you didn't realy manage to send. When you use dev cert to connect to prod env, you don't get any errors, but nothing happens. I encountered this behavior once. You should try to push to same token with prod cert.